# "app" from appJar undefined when using functions from a seperate module

Tags: python, user-interface

I have the code below that consist of the GUI for a program and currently two separate functions. In order to keep my main.py file somewhat neat I wanted to separate my functions into other files. However when I do this and import said file into main.py, when the code is run and I try to use the events related to imported functions, I get an Error that says "app" undefined. The problem is I am not sure how to define it in this case so that it would work.

Question is: How can I define app when using functions from another file?

**Full Error:** Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jason Smit\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 1702, in **call**
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Jason Smit\PycharmProjects\Project-X\venv\lib\site-packages\appJar\appjar.py", line 3494, in 
    return lambda *args: funcName(param)
  File "C:\Users\Jason Smit\PycharmProjects\Project-X\menu_events.py", line 10, in toolbar
    if app.exitFullscreen():
NameError: name 'app' is not defined

```
from appJar import gui

# Global Constants:

FILE_MENUS = ["Open", "Save", "Save as...", "Export", "Close"]
HELP_MENUS = ["Help", "Getting Started", "Settings", "Submit Feedback", "About"]


def login(btn):
    if btn == "Unlock":
        app.infoBox("Success", "Access granted\n Welcome User")
        app.hideSubWindow("Sub1")
        app.show()
    return

# Holds event handlers for toolbar


def toolbar(btn):
    print(btn)
    if btn == "LOGOUT":
        app.hide()
        app.showSubWindow("Sub1")
    elif btn == "FULL-SCREEN":
        if app.exitFullscreen():
            app.setToolbarIcon("FULL-SCREEN", "FULL-SCREEN")
        else:
            app.setSize("fullscreen")
            app.setToolbarIcon("FULL-SCREEN", "FULL-SCREEN-EXIT")


###################
# GUI starts here # 
###################


with gui("Project-X", "1700x1000") as app:
    app.setBg("white")
    app.setIcon("app_icon.ico")  # App icon

    # Subwindow for user login
    with app.subWindow("Sub1", "Login",):
        app.setBg("white")

        # Empty left container (To help get login in center.)
        with app.frame("LEFT", row=0, column=0, sticky='NEW', stretch='COLUMN'):
            """"""
        # Login container/gui

        with app.frame("CenterTop", row=0, column=1, sticky='NEW', stretch='column'):
            app.setBg("white")
            with app.labelFrame("Login"):
                app.setBg("white")
                app.setSticky("ew")
                # Login widget setup
                app.addLabel("Usr", "Name", 0, 0)
                app.addEntry("Name", 0, 1)
                app.addLabel("Pwd", "Password", 1, 0)
                app.addSecretEntry("Password", 1, 1)
                app.addNamedButton("Submit", "Unlock", login, 2, 0, 2)

        # Empty right container (To help get login in center.)

        with app.frame("RIGHT", row=0, column=2,  sticky='NEW', stretch='COLUMN'):
            """"""
    # Top-level menu for main window

    app.addMenuList("File", FILE_MENUS, toolbar)
    app.addMenuList("Help", HELP_MENUS, toolbar)

    # Main navigation Toolbar
    app.addToolbar(["LOGOUT", "FULL-SCREEN"], toolbar, findIcon=True)

    # Tabbed page for displaying info for each category
    with app.tabbedFrame("Item Inventory"):
        app.startTab("Category_1")
        app.addLabel("l1", "Test for category tab 1")
        app.stopTab()

        app.startTab("Category_2")
        app.addLabel("l2", "Test for category tab 2")
        app.stopTab()

    # Start application from login sub window
    app.go(startWindow="Sub1")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `login` and `toolbar` functions refer to the `app` object outside the scope of the line `with gui("Project-X", "1700x1000") as app:`. So the functions will need to be after that `with` line, indented once.

Alternatively, you might be able to pass the app object to these functions when you call them, but this seems circuitous (and I haven't tried anything like it) – since the functions are very much *about* the gui, they should be in the same file as the rest of the gui.

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot of sense. I was thinking that if I had all my gui functions in the same file it may get a bit clunky. However I see now that sometimes that is just something to live with :) Thank you again for your response. I appreciate it.